# Use Python seleniumwire with proxy authentication

Tags: python, selenium, geckodriver, seleniumwire

I am trying to access a url using proxy authentication whith username and password.

I have found a package which uses proxy authentication:
`selenium-wire` on https://github.com/wkeeling/selenium-wire

I have written the following code

```
from seleniumwire import webdriver

df_proxies=WebShare_Proxies()
args=df_proxies.values[random.choice(df_proxies.index)].tolist()

proxy_ip,proxy_port,username,password=args

url='https://fra.privateinternetaccess.com/pages/whats-my-ip/'

proxyString=username+":"+password+"@"+str(proxy_ip)+":"+str(proxy_port)

options = {
'proxy': {
    'http': 'http://'+proxyString,
    'https': 'https://'+proxyString,
    'no_proxy': 'localhost,127.0.0.1'
    }
}

driver = webdriver.Firefox(seleniumwire_options=options)
```

`WebShare_Proxies()` calls https://www.webshare.io/ API to get my proxies list
My proxy uses username and password for authentication

```
proxyString
'$myusername:$mypassword@45.95.96.187:8746'
```

I am having the following error when calling `webdriver.Firefox(seleniumwire_options=options)`

```
...in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: invalid argument: can't kill an exited process
```

Anyone has a clue how to overcome this error ?

Thank you for you consideration

Answer (score 1):

i think you misunderstood what seleniumwire is

seleniumwire is a package that enables you to inspect requests made by selenium as if you were inside chrome dev tools it does this by running a mitmproxy instance and proxying requests through it

mitmproxy is a debugging proxy that sits between a client (in this case selenium instance) and internet and allows you to intercept modify and inspect requests made by the client
you cant use more than 2 proxies with selenium so in order to use your own proxy you need to use a regular selenium instance

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
a = "proxyaddress:port:user:password"
chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=:{}'.format(a))
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
```